# Java instance lock and instance field lock difference

Tags: java, synchronization, synchronized

In following code one of the thread executes A() without any interference, but after that interference occurs. Shouldn't if a thread has acquired lock on the object, it would have have acquired locks on the fields as well?

```
Integer i=0;
  
synchronized A(){
    for(i=10;i>0;i--);
}
 
B(){
    synchronized(this.i){       // if i replace this.i with this it works as expected.
        for(i=10;i>0;i--);
    }
}
```

Comment: The lock is not on the **field** itself, but on the current value of the field. You shouldn't synchronize on fields that can change value, and you really shouldn't synchronize on instances of `Integer`, for one it could have unexpected effects due to the integer cache for autoboxing, and future versions of Java may disallow this when Integer becomes a value class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Shouldn't if a thread has acquired lock on the object, it would have have acquired locks on the fields as well?"

Short answer: No. The `synchronized`-keyword synchronizes only access to the specific object monitor (either explicitly given or implicit in case of method modifiers). It does not acquire any other locks on other objects, and does not care in any way about the values of the fields of the given object.

See also ["Intrinsic Locks and Synchronization"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) in the official Oracle turorials.

Comment: If a method is synchronized, another method(simple) can freely alter values of the same object?

Comment: Yes. it is up to the programmer to ensure it does not.

Comment: are object lock and object.field lock independent locks?

Comment: Yes, they are independent.